# do you know any service which allows hosting files and uploading and downloading them trough webservices?

Tags: web-services, file, hosting, flickr, photos

I want to create an application that needs to store xml and jpg files. Do you know any service on the internet that allows me to store files(jpg most important) and retrieve the files from the service when I need them?
I'm looking for something like flickr but with the option of manipulating files trough webservices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe use Amazon S3: http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

You can use their API to manipulate your files from different environments:

- Ruby on rails: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/8621639827664165
- .Net http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3051
- Etc.